# PS Import CSV into Listview

Tags: wpf, powershell, csv, xaml, listview

I'm writing a PS Gui where a listview is present. The CSV contains two columns, hostname for simply identifying and the associated ip-address of the host.

I'm having the problem, that the listview is importing the hostname or the address from the csv, depending on how the import-csv command looks like. If I change the $*.Adresse to $*.Server, the output of the listview looks like in the screenshot. Both columns are filled with the same info, with the hostname or with the addresses. The columns are the same for the csv and the xaml file.

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\verwaltungstool.csv"  | ForEach-Object {$var_ServerListe.Items.Add($_.Server)}
```

Now I would like to either keep both columns in the listview and by clicking on the address to recall a function. How can I tell PS to import both columns in the same way as it would look like without a gui, with format-table?
As an alternative I would like to "link" the hostname with the ip-address so that an Invoke-Command could work with that as the hostnames aren't resolvable.

The CSV looks like this:

```
Server,Adresse
TS1,192.168.x.x
```

The Xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Serverfalter" Height="500" Width="710">
    <Grid x:Name="Rückhand" Background="#FF323232" Cursor="Arrow" Focusable="True" AllowDrop="True" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="Version" Content="Version 0.3.2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="318,440,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" FontSize="10" Foreground="White" Height="23"/>
        <ListView x:Name="ServerListe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="153" Margin="20,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" Background="#FF646464" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="#FF828790" Visibility="Visible" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Server" Width="213"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Adresse" Width="130"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Serverliste importieren" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" Background="#FF5A5A5A" Foreground="White" FontSize="14"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu591.png)

Comment: Usually, to add items to a ListView, you would need `ForEach-Object { $lvi = [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]::new(); $lvi.Text = $_.Server; $lvi.SubItems.Add($_.Adresse); $var_ServerListe.Items.Add($lvi)}`

Comment: Don't forget to pipe the result of the .Add() to out-null.

Comment: @Theo Thanks, I tried it now like this: `Import-CSV "C:\temp\verwaltungstool.csv"  | ForEach-Object { $lvi = [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]::new(); $lvi.Text = $_.Server; $lvi.SubItems.Add($_.Adresse); $var_ServerListe.Items.Add($lvi)} | Out-Null` But the Gui Shows me under Server and Adresse "ListViewItem:{TS1}", somethings missing..